# Setting a system variable within a maven profile

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables

Is it possible within maven to set a system property that is attainable from within a java class.

I have seen that this is possible ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622121/pass-a-java-parameter-from-maven)) within the surefire plugin as follows;

```
String param = System.getProperty("my_parameter1");

<configuration>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
        <my_property1>${my_property1}</my_property1>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
</configuration>
```

However I would like to get a handle on the environment I am working in, I am already passing prod or dev as a maven profile argument - is it possible somehow to get a handle in the code on this either from setting a variable in the profile i call and then calling system.getProperty or some other way?

Thanks

**my pom file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>core</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.png</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.facebook4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>facebook4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>[2.0,)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relayrides</groupId>
            <artifactId>pushy</artifactId>
            <version>0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.threewks.thundr</groupId>
            <artifactId>thundr-mailgun</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>DEV</id>
            <properties>
                <swifte.url>jdbc:mariadb://ip:3306/swifte?autoReconnect=true</swifte.url>
                <swifte.username>user</swifte.username>
                <swifte.password>pass</swifte.password>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>resources</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>JavaPNSDev.p12</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>PROD</id>
            <properties>
                <swifte.url>jdbc:mariadb://ip:3306/swifte?autoReconnect=true</swifte.url>
                <swifte.username>username</swifte.username>
                <swifte.password>pass</swifte.password>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>resources</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>JavaPNSProd.p12</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should check out the [**exec-maven-plugin**](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

With the following configuration (notice the `<systemProperties>`)...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
        <arguments>
            <argument>argument1</argument>
        </arguments>
        <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
                <key>hello.world</key>
                <value>Hello Stack Overflow!</value>
            </systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

...and the following class...

```
package com.example;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String prop = System.getProperty("hello.world");
        System.out.println(prop);
    }
}
```

...and running a `package` (notice the phase in the configuration - you can change if you want, maybe to install), it prints out the value `Hello Stack Overflow!` from the key `hello.world`. So basically, the plugin executes your program when you build.

See also the [`exec:exec`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) goal. In the example, I used the [`exec:java`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) goal, but the two are different in how they function.

> [`exec:exec`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) executes programs and Java programs in a separate process.
>
> [`exec:java`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) executes Java programs in the same VM.

---

**UPDATE**

> Currently I am setting some values in properties based on the profile in my maven pom file. Is it possible to set this system property in the profile ? because really, i only have one pom file for dev and prod and its within the profile i would need to set it.

Yes, just use the `${property.name}` in the `<value>` element of the system property element. For example:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <id>world</id>
        <properties>
            <hello.world>Hello World!</hello.world>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <id>stack</id>
        <properties>
            <hello.world>Hello Stack Overflow</hello.world>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And the plugin `<systemProperties>`:

```
<systemProperties>
    <systemProperty>
        <key>hello.world</key>
        <value>${hello.world}</value>
    </systemProperty>
</systemProperties>
```

Just by changing the profile, to either `stack` or `world`, the message will print `Hello Stack Overflow` or `Hello World`, respectively.

---

**UPDATE 2**

Another plugin is the [properties-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/index.html). Nothing's been done on it in a while, but from a few tests, the necessary functionality is there.

It has a [`set-system-properties`](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/set-system-properties-mojo.html) goal along with some other [useful goals](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) to help ease properties management

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- any phase before your app deploys -->
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>hello.world.two</name>
                        <value>Hello World!</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: so i would want to use the exec maven plugin opposed to what i currently use being maven-compiler-plugin?

Comment: No they can go together. The exec plugin is just responsible for launching the program. The compiler plugin doesn't do that.

Comment: one final question if thats ok? Currently i am setting some values in properties based on the profile in my maven pom file. Is it possible to set this system property in the profile ? because really, i only have one pom file for dev and prod and its within the profile i would need to set it. I will post my pom now

Comment: is it necessary to define the main class and arguments parameters?

Comment: Arguments, no. But if you don't specify the class, then it won't know the launching point of the program, and the goal will fail. Remember the point of the plugin is to execute a program

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60400/discussion-between-biscuit128-and-peeskillet).

Comment: So it looks like the jboss-as-maven-plugin has a [deploy](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html) goal you can configure with a [beforeDeployment](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html#beforeDeployment) where you can pass command line commands

Comment: I think I found the one you need. Check my latest update. Tested on a webapp and it works as advertised

Comment: and this would be called in the same way i assume?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "called"

Comment: well we set the property in the goal, in the profile we would reference it in the same way and in my java class i would just do system.getproperty(value)?

Comment: Yea same way. All the properties get set in the `phase` you specify. As long as it's before the phase your app deploys, it should be fine. Try it out.

Comment: are you still around in chat?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, your answer is good and appreciable. I am also doing the same in my application but when I trying to get the property its giving me null. I have posted my issue in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49934111/unable-to-read-system-property-from-maven-in-java , Can you please help me out?