# How can I create maven profile to set system property

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-3

I need to create 2 maven profiles where I can set two different system properties. These profiles are just to set system property and not related any plugin.

like

```
<profile>
   <id> profile1 to set system property 1</id>
   .... set system property1
</profile>
<profile>
   <id> profile2 to set system property 2</id>
   .... set system property2
</profile>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a system variable within a maven profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604969/setting-a-system-variable-within-a-maven-profile)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, but it depends on what you need it for. This is the most common way of doing it:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>profile-1</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <properties>
                    <my-prop>Yabadabadoo!</my-prop>
                  </properties>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

but this only sets the system property during Maven's execution, so if you want (for instance) this class to pick it up:

```
package org.example;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args)      {
        System.out.println("-->" + System.getProperty("my-prop"));
    }
}
```

you need to run it with `mvn -P profile-1 compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.example.App` and it will yield the following result:

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) @ sys-prop ---
-->Yabadabadoo!
```

Running it without the `compile` goal will give you a `null` because the `exec` plugin is not bound to any build phase in this instance.

But if you need system properties for (say) unit tests, then the `surefire` plugin is what you need instead.