# Maven profile properties always give null when retrieve them

Tags: java, maven

In my pom.xml, I defined two profiles as australia and newzealand so based on the selected profile, I can retrieve the values that I defined in the properties.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.country</groupId>
    <artifactId>CountryProfileMavenDemo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <id>australia</id>
            <properties>
                <country.code>AU</country.code>
                <capital>Canberra</capital>
                <currency>AUD (Australian Dollar)</currency>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <id>newzealand</id>
            <properties>
                <country.code>NZ</country.code>
                <capital>Wellington</capital>
                <currency>NZD (New Zealand Dollar)</currency>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

For below code,

```
package codes;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class EnvironmentProfile {

    /*
    Based on the active Maven profile, Maven will set system properties (country.code, currency, and capital) accordingly.
      mvn clean install -P australia test
     To see which profile is active mvn help:active-profiles
     */
    @Test
    public void testPrintEnvironmentDetails() {
        System.out.println("Country Code: " + System.getProperty("country.code"));
        System.out.println("Capital City: " + System.getProperty("capital"));
        System.out.println("Currency: " + System.getProperty("currency"));
    }
}
```

From IntelliJ Studio I have selected the profile and ran the code, but I get output as

> Country Code: null Capital City: null Currency: null

I tried  with command line by using below command but no luck.

```
mvn clean install -P australia test -DskipTests=false
```

Comment: A maven profile which defines properties does not automatically system properties...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting a system variable within a maven profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604969/setting-a-system-variable-within-a-maven-profile)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion khmarbaise. I managed to solve by following it and put as an answer so  the community can refer it in the future.  Thanks a lot @aled as well.,

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve by referring the properties that defined in maven profiles in systemPropertyVariables as @khmarbaise suggested.

4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.country</groupId>
<artifactId>CountryProfileMavenDemo</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <id>australia</id>
        <properties>
            <country.code>AU</country.code>
            <capital>Canberra</capital>
            <currency>AUD (Australian Dollar)</currency>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <id>newzealand</id>
        <properties>
            <country.code>NZ</country.code>
            <capital>Wellington</capital>
            <currency>NZD (New Zealand Dollar)</currency>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version> <!-- Adjust version as needed -->
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <country.code>${country.code}</country.code>
                    <capital>${capital}</capital>
                    <currency>${currency}</currency>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Why do you need such profiles... within a test? Why not making different tests with the appropriate values?

Comment: This is just for a POC.

Comment: I would suggest to set thngs like that within your tests instead on the build level...